# HEAD detached, possibly after renaming a branch on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have a branch on GitHub, which I can see from the GitHub UI. When I try however to checkout this branch using the git client as follows:

```
git checkout my-branch
```

I'm receiving a detached HEAD message:

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
```

If I'm running however the checkout command with the --track option, I get the branch checked out as expected -

```
git checkout --track origin/my-branch
```

I assume that any other developer who tries to checkout this branch will face the same issue. This is because I tried cloning this repository in a new directory on my machine (to rule out any local git caching that can cause this) and faced the same issue.

There's a chance that this issue is related to the fact that this branch was renamed to a branch name that existed before and has been removed, but this is just a speculation of my part. I'd appreciate anyone's assistance with this issue.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `my-branch` is (also?) the name of a *tag*. Checking out a tag would put you in detached head mode.

Comment: That would be my first guess as well.

Comment: Thanks so much! Indeed, we had a tag with the same branch name. Deleting this tag resolved the issue.